# Proving a basic identity in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Consider the following following definition `definition phi  :: "nat ⇒ nat"  where "phi n = card {k∈{0<..n}. coprime n k}"` (see also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42319861/function-returns-0-when-it-should-return-1-eliminating-parantheses))

How can I then prove a very basic fact, like phi(p)=p-1 for a prime p ? Here is one possible formalization of this lemma, though I'm not sure it's the best one:

```
lemma basic:
  assumes "prime_elem (p::nat) = true"
  shows "phi p = p-1"
```

(`prime_elem` is defined in `Factorial_Ring.thy`)

Using `try` resp. `try0` doesn't lead anywhere. (A proof by hand is immediate though, since the GCD between any m less than p and p is 1. But poking around various file didn't turn out to be very helpful, I imagine I have to guess some clever lemma that I have to give auto for the proof to succeed.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `true` doesn't exist. Isabelle interprets this as a free Boolean variable (as you can see by the fact that it is printed blue). You mean `True`. Also, writing `prime_elem p = True` is somewhat unidiomatic; just write `prime_elem p`.

Next, I would suggest using `prime p`. It's equivalent to `prime_elem` on the naturals; for other types, the difference is that `prime` also requires the element to be ‘canonical’, i.e. `2 :: int` is prime, but `-2 :: int` is not.

So your lemma looks like this:

```
lemma basic:
  assumes "prime_elem (p::nat)"
  shows "phi p = p - 1"
proof -
```

Next, you should prove the following:

```
from assms have "{k∈{0<..p}. coprime p k} = {0<..<p}"
```

If you throw `auto` at this, you'll get two subgoals, and `sledgehammer` can solve them both, so you're done. However, the resulting proof is a bit ugly:

```
apply auto
apply (metis One_nat_def gcd_nat.idem le_less not_prime_1)
by (simp add: prime_nat_iff'')
```

You can then simply prove your overall goal with this:

```
thus ?thesis by (simp add: phi_def)
```

A more reasonable and robust way would be this Isar proof:

```
lemma basic:
  assumes "prime (p::nat)"
  shows "phi p = p - 1"
proof -
  have "{k∈{0<..p}. coprime p k} = {0<..<p}"
  proof safe
    fix x assume "x ∈ {0<..p}" "coprime p x"
    with assms show "x ∈ {0<..<p}" by (cases "x = p") auto
  next
    fix x assume "x ∈ {0<..<p}"
    with assms show "coprime p x"  by (simp add: prime_nat_iff'')
  qed auto
  thus ?thesis by (simp add: phi_def)
qed
```

By the way, I would recommend restructuring your definitions in the following way:

```
definition rel_primes :: "nat ⇒ nat set" where
  "rel_primes n = {k ∈ {0<..n}. coprime k n}"

definition phi :: "nat ⇒ nat" where
  "phi n = card (rel_primes n)"
```

Then you can prove nice auxiliary lemmas for `rel_primes`. (You'll need them for more complicated properties of the totient function)

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and improvement suggestions! I have a couple of unclarities: sledgehammer returns me for each prover output with a metis that invokes a lemma list that is different from our list - this surprises me, since I would have expected that the same versions of Isabelle running sledgehammer would find the same proofs. For example, here is my shortest list `(metis One_nat_def gcd_idem_nat order.not_eq_order_implies_strict prime_elem_nat_iff)`. Did you perhaps run other ATPs than cvc4 z3 spass e remote_vampire ? Or do you know were this discrepancy comes from ?

Comment: A second weird thing is that when I input your sledgehammer suggestion, i.e. `(metis One_nat_def gcd_nat.idem le_less not_prime_1)`, it gives me a warning saying `Metis: Falling back on "metis (full_types)"...` (my sledgehammer output runs without warning). Do you know what this warning means, where it comes from?

Comment: Lastly, did you had any specific properties of the totient function in mind, when you mentioned `rel_primes` ?

Comment: That warning comes from `metis`, I still have no idea what it means, but you can safely ignore it. And, yes, I did have specific properties in mind: `phi (a * b) = phi a * phi b` and, to a lesser extent, `prime p ⟹ k > 0 ⟹ phi (p ^ k) = p ^ k - p ^ (k - 1)`. The set `rel_primes` contains more information than the number `phi`, and factoring this out as a separate constant with separate lemmas makes the overall proof more structured.

Comment: I run Sledgehammer with the default options and the default set of ATPs and don't worry too much about it. There is also a lot of randomness involved in Sledgehammer and at some point it also used some kind of machine-learning techniques, so the results may vary over time (not sure if this is switched on by default nowadays). Sledgehammer's results are not meant to be reproducible; it's more like a long-shot attempt to find some proof by any means.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, one last-last question: If I try to modify your structured proof to your definition of `phi` at the end of your answer, somehow `by (simp add: phi_def)` isn't working any more, the output being [...]

Comment: [...]  `goal:No subgoals! Failed to finish proof⌂:goal (1 subgoal): 1. {k. 0 < k ∧ k ≤ p ∧ gcd p k = Suc 0} = {0<..<p} ⟹
    card (rel_primes p) = p - Suc 0` I'm not sure what to make of this output, as one hand hand it's saying that there's no subgoal that has to be proved on the other there is an unfinished subgoal. When I try to fix this, by using instead `by (auto simp add: phi_def)`, it remains purple forever, though I don't get a warning anymore. What does that mean ?

Comment: You probably also have to unfold `rel_primes_def`. If a proof method remains purple forever, it means that it doesn't terminate and that the corresponding proof did not finish. That is a problem that you must fix.